# Stored procedure parameter for range

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssrs-2012

This question is specifically for stored procedures to serve SSRS reports but I guess it can be applied to any stored procedure.

Often we send a range to a stored procedure to grab the data for that range. For example, get all customer data for customers whose name starts with 'A' to 'K'. On the client side I have a dropdown of all the customer names (with typeahead) and the user can choose a start and an end. In the dropdown I only show the name of the customer but I also have the Id of the customer. Now it is worth stating that this is just an example, I am not always looking for customer between 'A' and 'K'. There are times the range is for something completely different. For brevity, we will stick to customer names.

Let's say the user selected the following:

- Start: Elaine Benes (CustomerId: 199)
- End  : Jerry Seinfeld (CustomerId: 3)

Now I have 2 options for passing these parameters to the stored procedure.

1. Pass the names "Elaine Benes" and "Jerry Seinfeld"
2. Pass IDs 199 and 3. On the stored procedure side find the name of 199 and the name of 3 and use those.

If I go with Option 1, if the client is not using a dropdown with names from the customer table, they can pass any string. Option 2 forces them to send the ID of the customer. But option 2 will need to look up the Ids on the stored procedure side to find the name so some extra work needs to be done.

My question is **which options should I go with?** Any pros/cons to each approach?

Comment: Seems like you already know much of the pros/cons.  If you want to use *validated input*, then you generate the list from the actual data and you should then send the unique ID to the stored procedure.  This has the overhead costs you already mentioned.  If you don't need the input to be validated, then don't waste time looking up valid data or sending an ID to the stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just wanted to post this question in case others with more experience have other suggestions or pros/cons. I don't want to keep doing something a certain way if I am missing something big.